# Вычислить значения членов последовательности без использования массивов

Tags: c++

Найти `n` членов последовательности `X(1)=X(2)=X(3)=1; X(n)=X(n-1)+X(n-3)`,
т.е. с клавиатуры вводится n и нужно вывести:

> 1 1 1 2 3 4 6 9 13 19 28 41 и т. д. до n

Возможно ли выполнить эту задачу без использования массива?

Comment: по-моему, двойку пропустили:
    1 1 1 2 3 4 6...

Comment: А связанные списки не рассматриваются?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать рекурсию, здесь она наиболее очевидна. Либо цикл такого вида:

```
int a=1;
int b=1;
int c=1;
int d=2;
int t;

for (int i = 1; i<=n; i++)
{
  if (i < 4)
  {
    printf(i);
  }
  else
  {
    t=a+c;
    printf(t);
    b = c;
    c = t;
    a = b;
  }
  printf(" ");
}
```

Это будет немного эффективнее.

Answer (score 1):

Можно. Просто нужно хранить только последние 4 вычисленные элемента последовательности.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно. Ведь для вычисления каждого следующего элемента надо знать только три пердыдущих:

```
int xnm1 = 1, xnm2 = 1, xnm3 = 1;
cout << "1 1 1 ";
int n;
cin >> c;
for (int i = 4; i <= n; ++i) {
    int xn = xnm1 + xnm3;
    xnm3 = xnm2;
    xnm2 = xnm1;
    xnm1 = xn;
    cout << xn << " ";
}
```

Comment: Мне кажется, или объявление переменной в цикле - плохая затея? ;)

Comment: Почему? Вполне нормальный ход. Все равно компиляторы нонче оптимизирующие, так что вполне возможно, что пределы регистров процессоров эта "переменная" никогда и не покинет.